# Nested object destructuring: Duplicate declaration "fontSize"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I'm using [ShevyJS](https://github.com/kyleshevlin/shevyjs) with styled-components. The docs show an example that uses [nested object deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring) ...

```
const shevy = new Shevy()
const {
  baseSpacing: bs,
  h1: {
    fontSize,
    lineHeight,
    marginBottom
  }
} = shevy
```

and my styles ...

```
const Heading = styled.h1`
    font-size: ${fontSize};
    line-height: ${lineHeight};
    margin-bottom: ${marginBottom};
`;
```

It works fine. But, if I try to do the following I get an error `Module build failed: Duplicate declaration "fontSize"` ...

```
const shevy = new Shevy()
const {
  baseSpacing: bs,
  h1: {
    fontSize,
    lineHeight,
    marginBottom
  },
  p: {
    fontSize
  }
} = shevy

const Heading = styled.h1`
    font-size: ${fontSize};
    line-height: ${lineHeight};
    margin-bottom: ${marginBottom};
`;

const Byline = styled.p`
    font-size: ${fontSize};
`;
```

I've never worked with nested objects in this way before. I assumed the `fontSize` within the `p` would be scoped to `p` and the `h1` to `h1` so that `styled.p` knows which `fontSize` to use. It would certainly make sense but I highly doubt that's how it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Give it a unique name? Like `pFontSize`?

Comment: Which of those `fontSize`s do you want to use for `Byline`? But also just don’t do the CSS-in-JS thing

Comment: When destructuring you're assigning shevy properties to new variable names. These need to be unique. Why not just use the shevy property directly, `shevy.fontSize`?

Comment: @Ryan There is absolutely nothing wrong with using styled-components. It helps to maintain React components for one. Please give me a valid reason why it's bad.

Comment: @evolutionxbox True, that's much cleaner.

Comment: I understand why you'd want to have `${fontSize}`, but it looks like it will restrict you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've modified the question a bit to explain my original assumptions with nested object destruction. I thought the `fontSize` within the `p` would be scoped to the `p` property and `styled-components` would know which `fontSize` to use. A silly assumption.

Comment: https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your destructuring statement is basically equivalent to

```
const fontSize = shevy.h1.fontSize,
      fontSize = shevy.p.fontSize;
```

which is obviously invalid. If you want to destructure them, you need to assign them to different variables.

> I assumed the `fontSize` within the `p` would be scoped to `p` and the `h1` to `h1` so that `styled.p` knows which `fontSize` to use.

No, there is no such scoping, and it doesn't have anything to do with nested objects. All the variables in the destructuring target are declared in the same scope - and they are just normal `const` variables, nothing with a namespace attached or so.

Remember that `styled.p` is just a template tag, it does not know anything about variable names or could be able to affect them in any way. The expressions in the interpolation sections of the template are evaluated as usual, before their result *values* are passed into the tag function.

If you want to do some namespacing, you need to do it yourself explicitly:

```
const {
  baseSpacing: bs,
  h1: {
    fontSize: h1Fontsize,
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    lineHeight,
    marginBottom
  },
  p: {
    fontSize: pFontsize
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
} = new Shevy();

const Heading = styled.h1`
    font-size: ${h1FontSize};
/*               ^^ */
    line-height: ${lineHeight};
    margin-bottom: ${marginBottom};
`;

const Byline = styled.p`
    font-size: ${pFontSize};
/*               ^ */
`;
```